# Gcloud SDK cannot find aliased mysql client

Tags: mysql, bash, gcloud

I'm trying to get the gcloud SDK to use a mysql client that is aliased to a Docker run command.

First alias the mysql client:
`alias mysql="docker run --rm -it mysql mysql"`

I can tell this works because I get the expected output when running something like `mysql --help`.

However, when trying to run the connect command like this:
`gcloud sql connect $PROJECT_NAME --user=root --quiet`

I get an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) Mysql client not found.  Please install a mysql client and make sure it is in PATH to be able to connect to the database instance.
```

The gcloud SDK must be performing some checks and not getting what it expects.

Any help?

Thanks,

Juan